# Realm android ошибка при компиляции

Tags: java, android, realm

В Android Studio создаю класс MyClass

```
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.Ignore;


public class MyClass extends RealmObject {

    private String          name;
    private int             age;

    @Ignore
    private int             sessionId;

    // Standard getters & setters generated by your IDE…
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void   setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public int    getAge() { return age; }
    public void   setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
    public int    getSessionId() { return sessionId; }
    public void   setSessionId(int sessionId) { this.sessionId = sessionId; }
}
```

При компмляции появляются ошибки

> C:\App\MyApplication\app\build\generated\source\apt\debug\io\realm\MyClassRealmProxy.java
>   Error:(27, 40) error: illegal start of type Error:(27, 48) error:
>    expected Error:(28, 32) error:  expected
>   Error:(28, 60) error: ';' expected Error:(30, 5) error: illegal start
>   of expression Error:(47, 5) error: illegal start of expression
>   Error:(48, 5) error: illegal start of expression Error:(49, 5) error:
>   illegal start of expression Error:(49, 13) error: illegal start of
>   expression Error:(49, 19) error: ';' expected Error:(50, 5) error:
>   illegal start of expression Error:(57, 33) error: ')' expected

```
public class MyClassRealmProxy extends .MyClass
implements RealmObjectProxy, MyClassRealmProxyInterface {

static final class MyClassColumnInfo extends ColumnInfo {

    public final long nameIndex;
    public final long ageIndex;

    MyClassColumnInfo(String path, Table table) {
        final Map<String, Long> indicesMap = new HashMap<String, Long>(2);
        this.nameIndex = getValidColumnIndex(path, table, "MyClass", "name");
        indicesMap.put("name", this.nameIndex);

        this.ageIndex = getValidColumnIndex(path, table, "MyClass", "age");
        indicesMap.put("age", this.ageIndex);

        setIndicesMap(indicesMap);
    }
}

private final MyClassColumnInfo columnInfo;
private final ProxyState proxyState;
private static final List<String> FIELD_NAMES;
static {
    List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    fieldNames.add("name");
    fieldNames.add("age");
    FIELD_NAMES = Collections.unmodifiableList(fieldNames);
}

MyClassRealmProxy(ColumnInfo columnInfo) {
    this.columnInfo = (MyClassColumnInfo) columnInfo;
    this.proxyState = new ProxyState(.MyClass.class, this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("cast")
public String realmGet$name() {
    proxyState.getRealm$realm().checkIfValid();
    return (java.lang.String) proxyState.getRow$realm().getString(columnInfo.nameIndex);
}

public void realmSet$name(String value) {
    proxyState.getRealm$realm().checkIfValid();
    if (value == null) {
        proxyState.getRow$realm().setNull(columnInfo.nameIndex);
        return;
    }
    proxyState.getRow$realm().setString(columnInfo.nameIndex, value);
}

@SuppressWarnings("cast")
public int realmGet$age() {
    proxyState.getRealm$realm().checkIfValid();
    return (int) proxyState.getRow$realm().getLong(columnInfo.ageIndex);
}

public void realmSet$age(int value) {
    proxyState.getRealm$realm().checkIfValid();
    proxyState.getRow$realm().setLong(columnInfo.ageIndex, value);
}

public static Table initTable(ImplicitTransaction transaction) {
    if (!transaction.hasTable("class_MyClass")) {
        Table table = transaction.getTable("class_MyClass");
        table.addColumn(RealmFieldType.STRING, "name", Table.NULLABLE);
        table.addColumn(RealmFieldType.INTEGER, "age", Table.NOT_NULLABLE);
        table.setPrimaryKey("");
        return table;
    }
    return transaction.getTable("class_MyClass");
}

public static MyClassColumnInfo validateTable(ImplicitTransaction transaction) {
    if (transaction.hasTable("class_MyClass")) {
        Table table = transaction.getTable("class_MyClass");
        if (table.getColumnCount() != 2) {
            throw new RealmMigrationNeededException(transaction.getPath(), "Field count does not match - expected 2 but was " + table.getColumnCount());
        }
        Map<String, RealmFieldType> columnTypes = new HashMap<String, RealmFieldType>();
        for (long i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            columnTypes.put(table.getColumnName(i), table.getColumnType(i));
        }

        final MyClassColumnInfo columnInfo = new MyClassColumnInfo(transaction.getPath(), table);

        if (!columnTypes.containsKey("name")) {
            throw new RealmMigrationNeededException(transaction.getPath(), "Missing field 'name' in existing Realm file. Either remove field or migrate using io.realm.internal.Table.addColumn().");
        }
        if (columnTypes.get("name") != RealmFieldType.STRING) {
            throw new RealmMigrationNeededException(transaction.getPath(), "Invalid type 'String' for field 'name' in existing Realm file.");
        }
        if (!table.isColumnNullable(columnInfo.nameIndex)) {
            throw new RealmMigrationNeededException(transaction.getPath(), "Field 'name' is required. Either set @Required to field 'name' or migrate using RealmObjectSchema.setNullable().");
        }
        if (!columnTypes.containsKey("age")) {
            throw new RealmMigrationNeededException(transaction.getPath(), "Missing field 'age' in existing Realm file. Either remove field or migrate using io.realm.internal.Table.addColumn().");
        }
        if (columnTypes.get("age") != RealmFieldType.INTEGER) {
            throw new RealmMigrationNeededException(transaction.getPath(), "Invalid type 'int' for field 'age' in existing Realm file.");
        }
        if (table.isColumnNullable(columnInfo.ageIndex)) {
            throw new RealmMigrationNeededException(transaction.getPath(), "Field 'age' does support null values in the existing Realm file. Use corresponding boxed type for field 'age' or migrate using RealmObjectSchema.setNullable().");
        }
        return columnInfo;
    } else {
        throw new RealmMigrationNeededException(transaction.getPath(), "The 'MyClass' class is missing from the schema for this Realm.");
    }
}

public static String getTableName() {
    return "class_MyClass";
}

public static List<String> getFieldNames() {
    return FIELD_NAMES;
}

@SuppressWarnings("cast")
public static .MyClass createOrUpdateUsingJsonObject(Realm realm, JSONObject json, boolean update)
    throws JSONException {
    .MyClass obj = realm.createObject(.MyClass.class);
    if (json.has("name")) {
        if (json.isNull("name")) {
            ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) obj).realmSet$name(null);
        } else {
            ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) obj).realmSet$name((String) json.getString("name"));
        }
    }
    if (json.has("age")) {
        if (json.isNull("age")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Trying to set non-nullable field 'age' to null.");
        } else {
            ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) obj).realmSet$age((int) json.getInt("age"));
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

@SuppressWarnings("cast")
public static .MyClass createUsingJsonStream(Realm realm, JsonReader reader)
    throws IOException {
    .MyClass obj = realm.createObject(.MyClass.class);
    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String name = reader.nextName();
        if (name.equals("name")) {
            if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                reader.skipValue();
                ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) obj).realmSet$name(null);
            } else {
                ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) obj).realmSet$name((String) reader.nextString());
            }
        } else if (name.equals("age")) {
            if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                reader.skipValue();
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Trying to set non-nullable field 'age' to null.");
            } else {
                ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) obj).realmSet$age((int) reader.nextInt());
            }
        } else {
            reader.skipValue();
        }
    }
    reader.endObject();
    return obj;
}

public static .MyClass copyOrUpdate(Realm realm, .MyClass object, boolean update, Map<RealmModel,RealmObjectProxy> cache) {
    if (object instanceof RealmObjectProxy && ((RealmObjectProxy) object).realmGet$proxyState().getRealm$realm() != null && ((RealmObjectProxy) object).realmGet$proxyState().getRealm$realm().threadId != realm.threadId) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Objects which belong to Realm instances in other threads cannot be copied into this Realm instance.");
    }
    if (object instanceof RealmObjectProxy && ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRealm$realm() != null && ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRealm$realm().getPath().equals(realm.getPath())) {
        return object;
    }
    RealmObjectProxy cachedRealmObject = cache.get(object);
    if (cachedRealmObject != null) {
        return (.MyClass) cachedRealmObject;
    } else {
        return copy(realm, object, update, cache);
    }
}

public static .MyClass copy(Realm realm, .MyClass newObject, boolean update, Map<RealmModel,RealmObjectProxy> cache) {
    RealmObjectProxy cachedRealmObject = cache.get(newObject);
    if (cachedRealmObject != null) {
        return (.MyClass) cachedRealmObject;
    } else {
        .MyClass realmObject = realm.createObject(.MyClass.class);
        cache.put(newObject, (RealmObjectProxy) realmObject);
        ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) realmObject).realmSet$name(((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) newObject).realmGet$name());
        ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) realmObject).realmSet$age(((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) newObject).realmGet$age());
        return realmObject;
    }
}

public static long insert(Realm realm, .MyClass object, Map<RealmModel,Long> cache) {
    if (object instanceof RealmObjectProxy && ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRealm$realm() != null && ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRealm$realm().getPath().equals(realm.getPath())) {
        return ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRow$realm().getIndex();
    }
    Table table = realm.getTable(.MyClass.class);
    long tableNativePtr = table.getNativeTablePointer();
    MyClassColumnInfo columnInfo = (MyClassColumnInfo) realm.schema.getColumnInfo(.MyClass.class);
    long rowIndex = Table.nativeAddEmptyRow(tableNativePtr, 1);
    cache.put(object, rowIndex);
    String realmGet$name = ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface)object).realmGet$name();
    if (realmGet$name != null) {
        Table.nativeSetString(tableNativePtr, columnInfo.nameIndex, rowIndex, realmGet$name);
    }
    Table.nativeSetLong(tableNativePtr, columnInfo.ageIndex, rowIndex, ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface)object).realmGet$age());
    return rowIndex;
}

public static void insert(Realm realm, Iterator<? extends RealmModel> objects, Map<RealmModel,Long> cache) {
    Table table = realm.getTable(.MyClass.class);
    long tableNativePtr = table.getNativeTablePointer();
    MyClassColumnInfo columnInfo = (MyClassColumnInfo) realm.schema.getColumnInfo(.MyClass.class);
    .MyClass object = null;
    while (objects.hasNext()) {
        object = (.MyClass) objects.next();
        if(!cache.containsKey(object)) {
            if (object instanceof RealmObjectProxy && ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRealm$realm() != null && ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRealm$realm().getPath().equals(realm.getPath())) {
                cache.put(object, ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRow$realm().getIndex());
                continue;
            }
            long rowIndex = Table.nativeAddEmptyRow(tableNativePtr, 1);
            cache.put(object, rowIndex);
            String realmGet$name = ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface)object).realmGet$name();
            if (realmGet$name != null) {
                Table.nativeSetString(tableNativePtr, columnInfo.nameIndex, rowIndex, realmGet$name);
            }
            Table.nativeSetLong(tableNativePtr, columnInfo.ageIndex, rowIndex, ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface)object).realmGet$age());
        }
    }
}

public static long insertOrUpdate(Realm realm, .MyClass object, Map<RealmModel,Long> cache) {
    if (object instanceof RealmObjectProxy && ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRealm$realm() != null && ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRealm$realm().getPath().equals(realm.getPath())) {
        return ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRow$realm().getIndex();
    }
    Table table = realm.getTable(.MyClass.class);
    long tableNativePtr = table.getNativeTablePointer();
    MyClassColumnInfo columnInfo = (MyClassColumnInfo) realm.schema.getColumnInfo(.MyClass.class);
    long rowIndex = Table.nativeAddEmptyRow(tableNativePtr, 1);
    cache.put(object, rowIndex);
    String realmGet$name = ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface)object).realmGet$name();
    if (realmGet$name != null) {
        Table.nativeSetString(tableNativePtr, columnInfo.nameIndex, rowIndex, realmGet$name);
    } else {
        Table.nativeSetNull(tableNativePtr, columnInfo.nameIndex, rowIndex);
    }
    Table.nativeSetLong(tableNativePtr, columnInfo.ageIndex, rowIndex, ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface)object).realmGet$age());
    return rowIndex;
}

public static void insertOrUpdate(Realm realm, Iterator<? extends RealmModel> objects, Map<RealmModel,Long> cache) {
    Table table = realm.getTable(.MyClass.class);
    long tableNativePtr = table.getNativeTablePointer();
    MyClassColumnInfo columnInfo = (MyClassColumnInfo) realm.schema.getColumnInfo(.MyClass.class);
    .MyClass object = null;
    while (objects.hasNext()) {
        object = (.MyClass) objects.next();
        if(!cache.containsKey(object)) {
            if (object instanceof RealmObjectProxy && ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRealm$realm() != null && ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRealm$realm().getPath().equals(realm.getPath())) {
                cache.put(object, ((RealmObjectProxy)object).realmGet$proxyState().getRow$realm().getIndex());
                continue;
            }
            long rowIndex = Table.nativeAddEmptyRow(tableNativePtr, 1);
            cache.put(object, rowIndex);
            String realmGet$name = ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface)object).realmGet$name();
            if (realmGet$name != null) {
                Table.nativeSetString(tableNativePtr, columnInfo.nameIndex, rowIndex, realmGet$name);
            } else {
                Table.nativeSetNull(tableNativePtr, columnInfo.nameIndex, rowIndex);
            }
            Table.nativeSetLong(tableNativePtr, columnInfo.ageIndex, rowIndex, ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface)object).realmGet$age());
        }
    }
}

public static .MyClass createDetachedCopy(.MyClass realmObject, int currentDepth, int maxDepth, Map<RealmModel, CacheData<RealmModel>> cache) {
    if (currentDepth > maxDepth || realmObject == null) {
        return null;
    }
    CacheData<RealmModel> cachedObject = cache.get(realmObject);
    .MyClass unmanagedObject;
    if (cachedObject != null) {
        // Reuse cached object or recreate it because it was encountered at a lower depth.
        if (currentDepth >= cachedObject.minDepth) {
            return (.MyClass)cachedObject.object;
        } else {
            unmanagedObject = (.MyClass)cachedObject.object;
            cachedObject.minDepth = currentDepth;
        }
    } else {
        unmanagedObject = new .MyClass();
        cache.put(realmObject, new RealmObjectProxy.CacheData(currentDepth, unmanagedObject));
    }
    ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) unmanagedObject).realmSet$name(((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) realmObject).realmGet$name());
    ((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) unmanagedObject).realmSet$age(((MyClassRealmProxyInterface) realmObject).realmGet$age());
    return unmanagedObject;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    if (!RealmObject.isValid(this)) {
        return "Invalid object";
    }
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("MyClass = [");
    stringBuilder.append("{name:");
    stringBuilder.append(realmGet$name() != null ? realmGet$name() : "null");
    stringBuilder.append("}");
    stringBuilder.append(",");
    stringBuilder.append("{age:");
    stringBuilder.append(realmGet$age());
    stringBuilder.append("}");
    stringBuilder.append("]");
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

@Override
public ProxyState realmGet$proxyState() {
    return proxyState;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    String realmName = proxyState.getRealm$realm().getPath();
    String tableName = proxyState.getRow$realm().getTable().getName();
    long rowIndex = proxyState.getRow$realm().getIndex();

    int result = 17;
    result = 31 * result + ((realmName != null) ? realmName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + ((tableName != null) ? tableName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (int) (rowIndex ^ (rowIndex >>> 32));
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    MyClassRealmProxy aMyClass = (MyClassRealmProxy)o;

    String path = proxyState.getRealm$realm().getPath();
    String otherPath = aMyClass.proxyState.getRealm$realm().getPath();
    if (path != null ? !path.equals(otherPath) : otherPath != null) return false;;

    String tableName = proxyState.getRow$realm().getTable().getName();
    String otherTableName = aMyClass.proxyState.getRow$realm().getTable().getName();
    if (tableName != null ? !tableName.equals(otherTableName) : otherTableName != null) return false;

    if (proxyState.getRow$realm().getIndex() != aMyClass.proxyState.getRow$realm().getIndex()) return false;

    return true;
}

}
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Вы уверены, что "точка" перед именем класса тут не лишняя? `.MyClass` в JAVA разве можно использовать точку в имени класса?